# script to call a specific image for a specific date using a jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, onclick, datepicker

I am using the datepicker from jquery ui and I'd like add a script to call specific images to load when specific dates are chosen. Each date will have it's own unique image.

Any pointers of what is the best method to do this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datepicker`'s onSelect event which is triggered whenever you select any date from datepicker. In the callback you get the selected `date` object.

```
$('input').datepicker({
     onSelect: function(date){
          //Here you can check the specific date and do whatever you want
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it with a jquery onchange function on the original input field, if you want to handle user-entered dates as well.